# Passing information from jsp form to servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am quiet new to servlets and JSP really! I am trying to pass some information entered into a jsp form which depending on what is entered is passed to a different servlet which generated an excel document. There are four servlets in total.

My HtML/JSP code looks like this:

```
<form name="myform" method=post action ="">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Enter Region
<input type="text" Name="region"></td>
<td>Enter Weblogic Version
<input type="text" Name="version"></td>
<td>Enter Domain
<input type="text" Name="domain"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

A number of things, I have tried to specify the action as the servlet name but this doesn't seem to work.

The Servlets looks like follows

```
public class AppExcel extends HttpServlet
{
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException
{
    OutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
            String region = request.getParameter("region");
            String domain = request.getParameter("domain");
            String version = request.getParameter("version");
  .........
```

When I try to use these string variable it simply prints null to the screen. I have tried using a post form and a get form but see no difference.

**edit I should mentioned I'm using

```
 String redirectURL = "DBExcel";
 response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
```

to redirect to my servlet, my understanding is this is only available using doGet and not doPost.

Comment: There is only a POST form. No such thing as GET form. Just a quick tidbit to enhance your learning.

Comment: You need to use doPost() method not the doGet()...public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

Comment: I moved all the code to doPost and works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @Mechkov, what would be a form with the `method` attribute set as `GET` ?

Comment: @AxelH It would be a URL-appended GET request with query params.

Comment: @Mechkov, so you know, because you said `No such thing as GET form`. The form's values will be appended into the URL and will be process by the `Servlet.doGet()` methods. So there is GET Forms

Comment: @AxelH Technically, you are absolutely correct. From experience, i try to avoid using HTML Form submission with GET method - since GETs are limited in size. Anyhow, yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Mechkov, I will not discuss more in here because this is not the place, I agree with you, I limit miself to use GET forms for search forms (because those are good to see in the URL).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer below to move the code to doPost and use the set the form method to post

```
<form name="myform" method="post">
```

I also changed the call to the servlet from

```
response.sendRedirect("myServlet");
```

which seemed to only work with doGet, to call the servlet using

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("myServlet").forward(request, response);
```

This worked with the Post method and allowed me access to variable the user entered.